# Does not work on Netscape Navigator 3.0

Tags: bug, status-norepro, fun, april-fools, time-travel-mode

```
FROM: tigerjieer <tigerjieer@cs.uwaterloo.ca>
SUBJECT: Does not work on Netscape Navigator 3.0
NEWSGROUPS: alt.stackexchange.meta
```

Finally, after 20 years of suffering, StackOverflow now claims

[image]

Yet all I see is

[image]

**NOTHING!**

Have all those years been wasted? Have I endured 20 years of ``error: insufficient memory'', browser segmentation faults, and JavaScript exceptions just for this?

They lied to me!

All I want are some answers to my COBOL programming questions. Is that too much to ask for?

Someone, please, tell me.

*Netscape Navigator 3.0 on Windows 95b*

Comment: This seems like a network level bug, did you check your modem and if any kids are using the phone line?

Comment: Do you have Flash properly installed?

Comment: It is still loading. That is what the hourglass means.

Comment: I'm still using Mosaic and it's not any better. What is the difference between Mosaic and Netscape?

Comment: Best fun post of the Year. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Did you expect the site working at its best to be identical to what you normally see?

Comment: Can you see the future versions of other sites?

Comment: The devs here clearly hate Netscape 3.0 and Windows 95.  I'd find a different site with devs who actually care.  I'm so sorry. :(

Comment: Maybe you need to use IE 1. There were lots of sites that only worked with the One True Browser (well, maybe Netscape Navigator, too), and others that worked with Internet Explorer.

Comment: You are looking at stackoverflow.com. The "Best viewed in Netscape" panel only shows up when you're viewing a question.

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SO: [Netscape 3.0 not supported very well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382191/4642212).

Comment: I actually got an error popup when trying Stack Overflow with Netscape Navigator 3.04 on Windows XP, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326036/announcing-the-stack-exchange-time-machine/326112

Comment: IE 5 for Mac doesn't work either: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjhsL.png

Comment: @rene You should make that an answer, because it is correct. Stackoverflow was not launched until 2008, so assuming this is 1995 (Windows 95), the questioner still has to wait 13 years for the page to finish loading.

Comment: Have you tried Internet Explorer 1?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

OP must not have had Internet connection or incorrectly setup Windows 95, as the site is reachable, but Netscape uses SSLv2, which is way beyond deprecated.
[image: Pic]

In the background of the error message from SSLv2, is the closest I got by using HTTP and a forward-proxy to change it to HTTPS.

Comment: Hmm, so looks like all you'd need to get it working is to set up [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) with the `--ssl_version_client=SSLv2` [option](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-options/) and make Netscape trust its [certificate](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/). Nice. :)