# Announcing the Stack Exchange Time Machine

Tags: discussion, april-fools, time-travel-mode

We are living in the gold age of user-generated content. Anyone can post a joke before breakfast, become a meme by lunch and be fired for the joke at the end of business. Ok, it's more like the "[tin](http://www.infomine.com/investment/metal-prices/tin/all/) age", but still a unique moment in human history. Here at Stack Exchange, we're doing our part by hosting some of the very best content produced entirely by individual users at scale. I think it's fair to say we are the [Wikipedia](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wikipedias) of Q&A.

It all started back in [2008 with a site named after a class of bug](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html). Even so, it achieved some popularity within the developer community. The network first expanded to fairly technical topics, but very quickly [sites popped up](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) for just about every form of human knowledge including an endless variety of [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems) and [blockchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain) schemes. In the days BSE (Before Stack Exchange) it was certainly possible to share knowledge. There were podcasts and blogs and forums and [Geocities pages](https://web.archive.org/web/20091026234407/http://geocities.com/jlericson/). You could post on [someone's Wall](https://mic.com/articles/176599/the-facebook-wall-is-dead-social-network-struggles-to-get-personal-again#.PzYar9h8g) or [microblog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microblogging) or [be Tom's friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Anderson). And of course there were [wikis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wikis) and [social news](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_news_website) sites with alien mascots. But none of them capitalized on the simple genius of the question and answers format quite like Stack Exchange.

The [Web turned 30 this year](https://web30.web.cern.ch/) and we got to thinking it's too bad Stack Exchange sites have only been part of a third of that history. What, we pondered, would the world be like if Stack Exchange had started back in <strike>[the year 2000](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYk7QyZPNkU)</strike> 1998? Relieving you of the need to imagine it, we are proud to announce a new Time Machine feature that lets you experience Stack Exchange before its time.

[image: Y2K baby!]

What's that? It says "WELCOME TO STACKOVERFLOW" you say? I asked our designers about that and they tell me dank fonts don't need lower case. Oh, you mean why isn't it STACKEXCHANGE? That's a bit of a time travel paradox. We set the baseline at 2008, but the Stack Exchange brand didn't really show up until [a couple of years later](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/13/changes-to-stack-exchange/). We have our crack quantum mechanics working on it. Once they patch the timeline, we won't have any way of knowing.

As you explore the Stack Exchange off-ramp of the Information Superhighway keep your eyes peeled for content that could only exist in the '90s such as:

- [Crystal Pepsi](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9608/can-i-change-the-color-to-my-beer-to-an-arbitrary-color)
- [Spice Girls](https://superuser.com/questions/1161285/is-there-a-way-to-set-metadata-that-marks-a-song-to-not-play-when-friends-are-o)
- Funny [Jim Carrey](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53336/what-does-not-if-mean-here)
- [Descent secrets](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191135/how-do-you-trigger-doors-in-the-descent-1-level-titanium-falcon-military-depot)
- [Pokémon or Digimon?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/26294/who-came-first-pokemon-or-digimon)
- [Transgressive Simpsons](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/31554/the-simpsons-main-theme)
- [Unblemished Star Wars movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/in-what-order-should-a-newcomer-watch-star-wars-episodes)

Feel free to note especially appropriate examples in the answers below, but please don't [spoil *The Sixth Sense*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/130/why-isnt-bruce-williss-character-in-the-sixth-sense-self-aware).

Comment: Sadly, I need a real time machine to go back and fix the alarm I set improperly this morning.

Comment: I wonder what MyWhitespace.com would look like...

Comment: This looks positively _awful_ on systems that don't have Comic Sans installed. https://i.imgur.com/O3G9t86.png

Comment: Nice celebration. I reckon the SO/SE experiment has been one of the best in terms of peer-supported information sharing. Its philosophical underpinnings of freedom, responsibility and community place it far in advance of Wikipedia.

Comment: I though stackexchange had been *hacked!*  Since I came to it today from a Google search, I carefully checked the domain.  Every letter was right so that led me here.

Comment: @NonnyMoose That's one of my favorite parts on the iOS version.

Comment: NFR: That baby dancing gif on the footer

Comment: I think that you should limit count of (displayed) votes to 99 on this question due to some technical limitations of system.

Comment: At first I thought I landed onto a fake stackexchange website until saw this!

Comment: Something's not right with mine. Those trailing stars on the cursor, which I assume were done with activex, load way too quickly, and don't slow down my machine one bit.

Comment: How is this making me nostalgic for 1998 if I wasn't even born yet in 1998?

Comment: I added the frames and updated the resolution
https://imgur.com/adqT5ob

Comment: [WorldBuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) gets special treatment and it looks good.

Comment: 1st time I saw it I did a double-take. 2nd time I smiled. 3rd time, I sighed. But now I've seen it over and over again, and am fed up of turning it off on every single page I visit, it's **really** annoying. Can't you allow us to disable it once and for all once we've seen it? I'm almost in the mood of avoiding SO until your odd sense of calendar decides that Apr 1st has passed. FWIW, it's 10:15pm on Mar 31st here in the UK, and I've been seeing this thing for hours already. Past a joke.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel: Have you used the "Go to the future" button? Testing in incognito, that disables the feature on every question. Or do you mean every page you visit on other sites in the network too?

Comment: @JonEricson Do you really think people only want to disable this on one site? As in, "oh, it looks really stupid on _this_ site, but I really like it on _that_ site"? This perennial distinction between the different SE "sites" is getting really old. If I disable annoying crap once, I want it gone for good.

Comment: Disable only working on one site is dumb. I suspect that most of us who turned this disaster area off aren’t doing so because we think it’s too awesome.

Comment: What the heck is the Guestbook?

Comment: If Netscape 3 (for best viewing experience) won't install on a 64bit Windows, is that a Netscape issue, or a SysWow issue?

Comment: For fun, place the mouse cursor near the butt of the Unicron and move it around.

Comment: I had *wondered* what was going on.  Pretty funny, once I realized it was in purpose and not some very odd loaded-the-wrong-thing glitch

Comment: I shocked when I open stackoverflow today!!!!

Comment: Why doesn't it remember my selection that I do not want to see that? This is really annoying that I have to disable this stupid look every time I look at an answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: There was a bug that prevented the cookie from working across the site, but that was fixed very early. I tested it just now and I can't reproduce the problem. It's a per-site cookie, so maybe you are looking at another site?

Comment: It's actually annoying and distracting

Comment: And what's the date today? It's funny!

Comment: This is delightfull. Especially the mouse cursor :)

Comment: This made my day  Unicorns! Yeah! It'll show the kids that coding can be fun :)

Comment: @JonEricson Hadn't noticed that amongst the garish design! Also, you get a pop-up near the top toolbar, which distracts from the left side. Clicked it now, and it does seem to have disabled it for this site. Looks like I have to do this for each site individually, which is annoying, but at least it's not every question now! Thanks

Comment: Glad some one's having fun, but for the people that have just about had it with the things SE has gotten/still gets wrong, this distracting, annoying abomination will certainly push some of them over the edge.

Comment: I love how to background colour of the "welcome to stackoverflow" image does not match the background colour on which it is shown. I never understood the problem but had to fight with it quite often back in the days :D.

Comment: Why is this new look not longer on the main site? Did I accidentally opt out? How do I get it back?

Comment: Why it is not a global toggle among all stackexchange.com sites? It's super annoying to disable it for every site.

Comment: @NonnyMoose Weird to find something that's actually *improved*—however slightly—by the addition of Comic Sans.

Comment: Can we get a new look for the chat too?

Comment: This is freaking glorious

Comment: So I got the required reputations points to comment here by my answer earlier. thanks to Stack Exchange community, can we have customized cursor too? Like we used to add different cursor with custom picture back in the day. Would be so cool I guess.

Comment: @Gui Please refrain from asking separate questions on other people's threads, open your own new thread.

Comment: Next year can we send the time machine back a bit farther? This 90's style brings back some memories, but I'd really love to revisit the BBS days of the mid-80's.

Comment: A launch on April 1st, huh?

Comment: Messi Is GOAT. Cheers. ⚽

Comment: I have not problem with this. I am a programmer and thus used to have annoying text in front of me all day.

Comment: *"keep your eyes peeled for content that could only exist in the '90s such as...funny Jim Carrey"* omg should I call the cops to do a wellness check on Jim because that kind of burn is life threatening.

Comment: It's not legit unless it's formatted with `<table/>` elements. I'm seeing too many `<div/>`'s

Comment: The sparkly stuff on the mouse is annoying, but it is kind of funny too.

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib this is meta post - it isn't a question. Your comment would make sense IF you addressed everyone else that asked a question they don't really need an answer for in meta posts... I find your lack of consistency confusing.

Comment: @Gui I find your lack of sarcasm receptors, funny.

Comment: For fun I ran one of these pages through an accessibility tool... 81 errors. Glad we have evolved.

Comment: how do I keep this forever?

Comment: How did you code the glitter that appears when you move the mouse?

Comment: I thought I had caught a virus.

Comment: Incidentally, Internet began in the 1960s with [(D)ARPAnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPANET).

Comment: I like the Viewed Counter it is like old petrol pump meter reading ;)

Comment: Very cool fature :D

Comment: @NonnyMoose: This looks positively awful on systems that *do have* Comic Sans installed.

Answer (score 246):

Although the page footer saying

> Best viewed in Netscape 3.0

StackExchange websites can't really be opened by Netscape 3 due to unsupported algorithms for TLS.

[image: Error in Netspace Navigator 3.04]

Comment: Ahaha looks like the devs didn't test for this! Good spot

Comment: Is that netscape for sale ?

Comment: Netscape actually handled that reasonably.

Comment: Please submit a bug report to have this resolved!...

Comment: holy shit this is good. You've got more points as a new contributor than most get in 10 years of actively trying to answer questions,

Comment: That takes me back to my college days in the late 90s, every computer used Netscape Navigator. I don't know if Firefox existed back then, fairly certain that Chrome didn't exist back then

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Umm, Firefox is a direct successor of Netscape Navigator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla#History

Answer (score 209):

I find your lack of **<blink>** tags **</blink>** disturbing.

Comment: I found the lack of midi or any webrings jarring!

Comment: Well that's only to be expected - this site is best viewed with Netscape. <blink> is an IE-only thing, to compete with Netscape's <marquee>.

Comment: Trying to edit my stack overflow profile to include any random HTML and Javascript which I see fit.  Instructions unclear.  Plz add me on MSN Messenger and send more info.

Comment: did you deliberately get those the wrong way around @JiriTousek?

Comment: @v25 MSN Messenger? That new stuff from Microsoft? No way. I'll stick to ICQ.

Comment: Or purple visited links…

Comment: It's totally missing the "ripple" logo Java applet.

Comment: [For anybody wondering about the out-of-universe reason for this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555592/2127008)

Answer (score 87):

Had Stack Exchange (and all the supporting infrastructure) been around in 1998, the 'Y2K bug' would have been a flash in the pan.

- Q: Why does my system crash?
- Response: Question closed for *lack of research*.

Then again, maybe not. :P

Comment: Q: Will my nuclear reactor core melt with y2k bug? A: Closed as off-topic. | Few moments later at a distant far, loud * * explosion * * echoes.

Comment: Don't forget the ensuing snarking in the comments.

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib We need more detail, what have you tried? Otherwise this needs closing for being too vague

Answer (score 85):

I have only one thing to say: **KEEP THE GUESTBOOK!**

[image]

I mean, who *wouldn't* want to tell the world "OMG HAHAHA"?

Comment: OMG HAHAHAHA !!!ONEONEONEELEVENTYONE!!!!!!

Comment: Isn't that thing fake anyway? I always see the very same messages scrolling through. D:

Comment: @RayKoopa I'm sure it is. They are the same and I've never seen anything custom (from other users).

Comment: @val Yeah, now where I scroll through the list, it becomes obvious they're picked from a random set of messages and actually repeat D:

Comment: When you look at the page source you can find an array containing all those comments, probably being regularly picked from and added to the pile

Comment: I signed the guestbook on parenting and it showed up in the feed at least once...

Answer (score 57):

I love this - the only thing I'm really surprised at is the seeming omission of the visitor counter.

How are we to know how many 1337 h4xx0rs have visited each page???

But this is great - reminds me when Geocities was the pinnacle of what the Internet had to offer :)

Edit: Well, silly me. I didn't see it by the OP, I was expecting to see it at the bottom above/below the guestbook.  I know know how many h4xx0rs have seent it :D

Comment: I see a visitor counter. I must have hacked too much time.

Comment: I like how this is one of the parts of the old web that was kept in most modern websites with user generated content. I almost feel like adding one of those odometer counters to my blog home page

Answer (score 55):

Just tried it on my i486DX with dial-up and Mosaic-browser and it looks as expected. The only downside was that I had to wait for 27 minutes for the page to load.. ;)

[image]

Answer (score 53):

This is great!  But I'm having trouble with one thing -- your frames aren't adjustable!  I tried and tried and I couldn't get the controls to pop up over the division between the left and right frames.  Also, isn't there supposed to be a line between them?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Maybe they used tables instead...

Comment: @awizardarachnid oh, that could be it!  I mean, frames are clearly the superior choice (that's an awful lot of stuff to pack into a table cell), but they also did [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5BqL.png), so something funky is going on.

Comment: I believe you need at least Netscape 2 or IE3 to view HTML frames.

Comment: I'm using Netscape 3.  The page announces that it supports that version!  It's so frustrating...

Answer (score 52):

April fool day

[image: April fool day]

Comment: OOOOH now I get it

Comment: Holy Sh*t!! this guy gets it!!! Are you a hacker dear sir?

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib He is Madara Uchiha of the Uchiha clan. Maybe he read about this on the Uchiha stone tablet ;P

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib i used my mangekyou sharingan . lol

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib nope, i'm not a hacker. i just viewed source code of this page

Answer (score 50):

First of all, you need two versions of this page:

[image]

"Under Construction" should be a link leading to an empty page with the following information:

[image]

Also, each page must have this gadget with as many digits as possible:

[image]

The number should increment on every page refresh.

And don't forget to add this:

[image]

Answer (score 34):

**It STILL does NOT run with 640K memory!!**

You need to free more conventional memory!!!
*****^^^^^^^+++++++______+++++^^^^^^^******

Comment: LOADHIGH !
HIGHMEM !

Comment: My first idea was that you're speaking brainfuck

Comment: QEMM is your friend.

Comment: This is way to heavy for my 14k4 modem :(

Comment: Don't forget to press the TURBO button

Answer (score 29):

I've been seeing the unicorn like this the whole time:

[image]

Comment: I’m envious — I only get the back end of a unicorn.  For all I can see, it could be just a horse!

Comment: @PLL [The front of the unicorn doesn't show up if you have the sidebar disabled.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326133/152515) You just get a unicorn butt in that case.

Comment: Does not show at all on 15" laptop screen (unless you zoom out)

Comment: Wer unicorns a thing in the 90s' internet? I have no memories of unicorns on the internet before twitter.

Comment: If it's not inappropriate to 'invite' you like this, I'd love to hear what you have to say here: [Checking in with the Lavender community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337802/187282).

Answer (score 25):

Beautiful tribute to the internet's 30th birthday.
Loved the comic sans.

The team at StackOverflow knows what's up. Proud of you :) :) :)

Comment: The internet is like 50 years old. I think you mean the web's.

Comment: you're correct.

Answer (score 24):

I think I've disabled this about a dozen times now, and I expect at least a few more today :|.

That is: both of the computers I use, each of my browser profiles on both of those computers, as well as every single site in the Stack Exchange network.

**This really needs to have a single disable for all sites** (either using cookies, if possible, or storing a setting on one's user profile, although this won't help with anonymous visitors).

Comment: OMFG yes I am tired of having to disable this every time I open a new site I haven't yet visited yet today. It was funny for about 30 seconds, I enjoyed it, waved my mouse around and watched the sparkles. I am significantly less enthused having been smacked in the eyeballs for the _n_ th time today.

Answer (score 21):

Check it out:

[image: Editing with WINWORD.EXE]

Comment: Good old Clippy!

Answer (score 19):

Can you please make it work on profile and homepage as well? It only works when I'm on an actual question, and that makes me sad

Answer (score 19):

Thank you for rescuing me from....

..the barrage of web perfection,

the high expectations, the sleepless nights, of debugging syntax, obsessing about border spacing, my inferiority complex, at not getting it right first time, the crazy ugly neatness, mind numbingly created by armies of...

Zombies like me. Brainwashed into forgetting how things used to be...

Although... if you really want to impress me, MAKE THIS BLINK. In rainbow colors.

Once again, thank you for making my day.  Thank you for making me feel a little bit more human, and a little less numb. Thank you for making the Web a friendlier place, a little more human, always.

We love you!

Edit: I just noticed the color of the left bar changing as I scroll down. Wheee!!! That's so cool!
Edit: Wheee!!! Glitter in Chromium!

Comment: ...And just like that, the most glorious day on stackexchange, is gone :-o over, evaporated, to quote a famous PBX, no let's not... oh, but it's not! Hurraah!!! Someone asked a better question than me! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326037/will-there-be-an-option-to-permanently-keep-this-years-april-fools-design-activ

Answer (score 19):

It may not be very popular, but can I keep it for longer?
It keeps a good mood ;]

Comment: See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326037/388442

Comment: The xkcd commandline which started as a April Fools Joke is [still available years later](https://uni.xkcd.com)

Comment: @gerrit: Why can I not type at that commandline?  I was going to test whether it produced appropriate output for `make -f me a.sandwich` and `sudo make -f me a.sandwich`.

Answer (score 16):

> Y2K jokes

For those nostalgic about unwarranted doomsday calling, this April 6th we are getting the 1024‑weekly GPS rollover, just saying.

Comment: and the new generation is not much better: 2 more bits but only a 8096 weeks rollover...

Comment: Are bits really that hard to come by on GPS hardware?

Answer (score 16):

Can we keep this? It's better than the "responsive" theme dumped  on the beta sites?

Answer (score 14):

MEMORANDUM

To: Design Department

From: Time Continuity Bureau

Subject: Navigation Enhancement

Message: Urgent, please use over designed graphical elements for the navigational links. Attached are examples for use (including "hover states") which have been submitted by the Dept. of Authenticity. Your designers may use them freely without concern for copyright as they do not "officially" exist in your time.

Be aware that failure to comply with this request has catastrophic effects in our time!

[image]

Comment: You mean 'effects'?

Comment: Not enough drop shadow on the text itself. It has to be as much as on the button, otherwise it's imbalanced and looks off. Also how the hell did you antialias the text so well?

Comment: @dimmech You know I was only kidding ;P

Comment: Don't forget the Java applets to make the buttons react on mouseover.

Answer (score 14):

This is nice and all, but I've noticed a troubling use of GIFs. [As we all know](https://burnallgifs.org/archives/), Unisys is trying to enforce their patents and charge us for using their new-fangled image format. We should remove all GIFs and become a certified GIF-free zone, at least until 2003 when the patent expires!

We need to replace all GIFs and add this to the footer:

> [image: gif free zone]
>
> This site is certified GIF-free. All images on this site are either JPG or PNG. Unisys are trying to charge all webmasters $5000 for the use of GIF images, which are patented.
>   Don't let them get away with it!

Comment: Haha I just posted a GIF and then read your answer :)

Comment: s/copyrighted/patented/, or is that part of the joke?

Comment: @NathanTuggy, [No joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Unisys_and_LZW_patent_enforcement).

Answer (score 13):

I like this even more than [Space Jam](https://www.spacejam.com/archive/spacejam/movie/jam.htm).

[image]

Comment: A much superior URL https://www.warnerbros.com/archive/spacejam/movie/jam.htm

Comment: @Won't Dumb question maybe, why is that one superior?

Comment: The warnerbros generic domain adds just a bit more piquant flavor to it. It's so rustic.

Comment: @Won't Right you are. You have good taste.

Answer (score 13):

This is not the **[real thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)**. ;)

[image]

I've created an update for your message board that is compatible with all internet browsers:

```css
body {
  background-color: #0C0D0E;
}

marquee {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #32E830;
}
```

```html
<marquee>
  <img src="https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Img/april-fools-2019/headline.gif?v=f81430a4e488" alt="Welcome to Stack Overflow">
</marquee>
```

Answer (score 13):

It really is better in Netscape Navigator 3.0 :D
[image]

I've been using 2.0 for years, thanks for the heads up on the newer version!

Answer (score 12):

The wizard for creating a new question should be guided by clippy.

Comment: Shhhh! No spoilers for next April 1.

Comment: Not that far of a reach: https://www.smore.com/clippy-js

Answer (score 11):

I like the fact that it's actually **Proudly** built in notepad

But, VIM for life everyone

P.S. don't start a emacs vs vim battle

P.P.S. Did they just say that this site was built in Windows? Win 98?

Comment: emacs vs vim....

Comment: You know, stack exchange actually use windows servers.

Comment: Hmm. Does it have CR or CRLF line endings in the source code?

Comment: @val could you please share the source

Comment: @VarunChhangani It's true. They use IIS and write stuff in .NET.

Comment: VIM 7.4 or earlier +1.

Comment: emacs + vim = vimacs

Answer (score 10):

Mercy! Please, mercy!! Make it stooop!!!

Well at least a meta posting debut to remember..

Please save it somewhere once it is stopped. :)

Answer (score 9):

My only reaction is to say "what in the fresh bowels of hell is this nonsense?".

I don't need to turn it off at every individual site - just each one where it's happening - which I don't know until I go to them. Great, more toggles to muck around with.

Please, stop doing things that aren't thought-out.

Comment: Hey, what are you doing outside of the office of the national treasury? Get back in there, never mind us.

Comment: The April Fool's Ebenezer! Sounds like an interesting username ;)

Comment: You must be deep in some project and forgot the date.

Comment: Oh, it being April Fools Day makes it perfectly acceptable to reduce accessibility and mess with people's heads in harmful ways that Stack Exchange has hypocritically spent months telling us it is trying to avoid? Cool! Nobody else at all had tried to explain that to me in an implicit passive-aggressive way! Thanks.

Comment: @Loophole Or maybe after 15 years of this nonsense on the internet, some of us have had enough of it.

Answer (score 7):

You'll always find your mouse pointer:

[image: Ask Ubuntu star trail mouse pointer.gif]

Comment: My favorite feature.

Answer (score 6):

I want to add comments but it turns out I need more reputation points. Yes I need to travel to future to add comments on this post.

Answer (score 6):

I thought it would be interesting to see how this impacted new users, so I gathered some statistics about how many new users created an account on Stack Overflow during the last 24 hours compared to the same period previous weeks. I looked at how many Stack Overflow accounts were created between Sunday 19.51 UTC and Monday 19.51 UTC this week (when the time machine was enabled) and the previous weeks (when the time machine didn't exist). This is what I found:

- Today: 8398 new Stack Overflow users
- 1 week ago: 5143 new Stack Overflow users
- 2 weeks ago: 5227 new Stack Overflow users
- 3 weeks ago: 6082 new Stack Overflow users
- 4 weeks ago: 5280 new Stack Overflow users

This means that 55% more users created a Stack Overflow account today than on a normal Monday. I'm not sure why this is, but looking at the numbers, this doesn't seem to be a coincidence. Maybe the new users liked the time machine. Maybe they were annoyed by [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325996/349538) and thought creating an account would solve the problem. Maybe there are other reasons that I haven't thought of.

Comment: hillarious, absolutely hillarious

Answer (score 5):

I don't mind this for the most part, but this rule:

```css
.container .favicon {
    background-image: url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/april-fools-2019/broken-image.png?v=a2722a3b4e69");
    background-position: 0px;
}
```

is kind of obnoxious. I like being able to tell which site a question is from, and this single-handedly forces me to disable the joke.

Comment: I am sure you have much bigger gripes than this though... with an alias like that... you are in my thoughts and I hope you survive this heartless web of confusion, intact, to tell the tale, one day...

Answer (score 5):

It's beautiful! Brings back memories of back in the day when I would load my interwebz floppy disk and connect my dial-up modem and browse on myspace, waiting 45min to load each page. Then I would turn on my TTS add-on and play text-based DND. Then I would connect to some government computer and play simulated nuclear warfare. Ah, memories!

*Disclaimer: I may or may not have any knowledge of what life was like in 1998.

Comment: That sounds accurate enough for what life was like in 1998.

Comment: @doppelgreener And I may or may not be relying on a knowledge of computers and the movie Wargames

Answer (score 4):

I think this annoying background show how much StackExchange cares about its end users. I had a late night session resolving some production issues and struggled to read the answer, because of its annoying font and colours and was not quite wake enough to figure out I could disable this background.

Why has Stack Exchange done this ? I do not even find it remotely funny ? Could you not think of better ways to pull an April's fool prank without affecting the usability of the side for end users who really need to use it.

Comment: Click to clock to disable.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out eventually, however, I was pretty bleary eyed by that time and it took me ten minutes to find the clock.

Comment: And in that state you believe it possible you were doing quality work? You couldn't even find a theme toggle.

Comment: The normal content wasn't covered directly by the backgroud image.

Comment: I was not after quality work, but a quick bug fix to resolve issues caused by someone else's release. The normal content wasn't covered, however, it was pretty hard to read given the font and the fairy dust stars. I was more focused on finding the right answer rather than finding the right UI toggle.

Answer (score 4):

Needs a "Punch the Monkey" banner ad.

(Or two, for the full computer-bogging experience.)

Answer (score 3):

I think it should also have a lot of pictures of random cats.

Answer (score 3):

The theme is impressively responsive.

I give it a C minus for the aforementioned reason.

Answer (score 3):

As expected from Stack overflow, they done something special on special day.

Today I whole day used 90's theme (although many times just scrolling mouse :) )

Great Job..

Congratulations to whole team :)

Answer (score 3):

You guys forgot to change the page layout on the stack sites to use 
html `<table>`'s so that's it feels more retro

Comment: Why would you downvote html tables?

Comment: [Asked on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382193/why-is-the-new-website-design-not-using-tables-for-alignment)

Answer (score 3):

Shout out to the responsive design team at SO in the 90s. Was very much expecting a horizontal scroll bar :)

[image]

Comment: I see the downvote trolls still exist in the 90s

Answer (score 3):

Won't load using Internet Explorer 5 on my Mac! (You're not alone, Netscape users)

[image: IE:mac]

Answer (score 3):

1. Either your Netscape button is broken, AOL is too busy to take me to it, or my modem is too slow. But I got a 56k modem, so I know it's not a problem with my connection speed.
2. I'm working on a program and running into problems. Do you have any resources for programming in HyperCard?
3. What would really make this theme great would be a place to click to save 1 square foot of rainforest.

**Thanks for the fun April Fool's Day/Unicorn/sparkles/time machine theme!**

Answer (score 2):

Captain Marvel says hello. My Geocities page may or may not be jealous. The mouse pointer is sheer bloody genius and the only recommendation I would make for this page is MOAR FRAMES. FRAMES EVERYWHERE.

Oh, what's your AOL keyword? I might have some hours to use on there still and I need to change my status message.

Answer (score 0):

**Best thing i have seen so far**

[image: Best thing i have seen so far]

Answer (score -1):

[image: I ain't even mad]

Answer (score -2):

It irks me more than it should that the 'birth of Stack Overflow' page that you linked to contains a reference to Jeff Atwood starting to "rack in the dough" rather than rake. I know it was 11 years ago, but can that be fixed...please?

Comment: Can we be sure it didn't refer to [this object](https://images.discerningassets.com/image/upload/c_fit,h_1000,w_1000/c_fit,fl_relative,h_1.0,l_deco_watermark,o_40,w_1.0/v1452890372/Bread_Rack_iow71b.jpg) instead?

Answer (score -4):

I am really disappointed that you didn't put something better, like for example showing score in millions, so we all feel super1337 like mr skeet. Maybe an idea for next 1st April.

Answer (score -7):

I am using Dark Reader to use my browser with a dark theme. I don't know about the rest of you, but this is the most annoying thing that has ever been done to me! It's like living in a nightmare!

I understand becoming old is depressing. We all would like to return to our youth, but is this the most constructive way to do it?

I also understand you Americans and probably two more countries around the world make a silly celebration on April 1st. For the rest of the world, it's just freaking annoying. Imagine how you'd feel if I entered your barn and stole your donkey on December 28th, because that's how I'm feeling right now. If you want to make this site international, don't misrepresent 90% of the world.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1172/ ...

Comment: Whatever the barn/donkey celebration is, I want in. I’m shopping for a barn and donkey on Amazon right now. I’ll expect you on 12/28.

Comment: Is it really stealing them, or is it more of a donkey swap? Plush donkeys are ok right? We normally celebrate Regift or Return day on the 28th but this sounds fun. I wonder if RR day is actually related to this donkey thing. Maybe people loaded up their donkeys with ill-fitting sweaters and horrifyingly ugly vases and such before they were “stolen”? What a great way to have an answer for your mother-in-law when she asks after that lamp! Sorry it was stolen, so sad.

Comment: Wow, nothing like a bit of anti-American bigotry to get the juices flowing.

Comment: Why is it bigotry? Just keep your local celebrations local, as everybody else does. For me, it's just a few days on which the site was virtually unusable for no reason.

Comment: "Imagine how you'd feel if I entered your barn and stole your donkey on December 28th, because that's how I'm feeling right now." You're country's lame.

Comment: [WP has a list of the countries that celebrate April Fools or a similar holiday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day#Longstanding_customs). Turns out, most of Europe has such a tradition, and Latin America does something similar… oddly enough, on Dec 28. Is that actually what you're referring to?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Sure!