# Unicorn shows butt only when sidebar disabled

Tags: bug, design, april-fools, unicorns

When my friend shouted "UNICORNS" when I told him about the cool new April Fool's styling, I didn't understand why he said that. 
[image]

Since unicorns are such magical creatures it'd be very rare to spot one in the wild. Especially for those people who have disabled the sidebar from the user options menu.

Dear SE, could I also share in the laughter by getting this fixed?

Comment: SE not supporting other than Zoom 100%.