# What's with this weird design and stars coming out of my mouse pointer?

Tags: support, april-fools, time-travel-mode

My Stack Overflow gives me a weird design and stars coming out of my mouse pointer. WTF? How do I get rid of them?

Comment: It will disappear in about two hours (once it's no longer April 1 anywhere in the world).

Comment: I think this thing was a very bad idea.

Comment: @Christine most jokes are funny only for part of the people. It's impossible to find a joke that everyone in the world will actually like.

Answer (score 4):

Click on "Go to the future" and you can forget the past.

[image: Click here]

Answer (score 1):

This "weird" design you mention is actually Stack's dedication to the Internet's 30th Birthday combined with an April Fools joke.

You can click the clock icon at the top right-hand corner of any page (next to your Inbox icon) to go back to the future (a.k.a. to the current design).

More info here: [Announcing the Stack Exchange Time Machine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326036/announcing-the-stack-exchange-time-machine)

Comment: I found it very annoying.